# What happens if we use async reset block with sync reset?

Tags: verilog

Consider that I have a common verilog module that I want to be exported to 2 different kinds of designs - one on sync reset and the other on async reset.

What would be the right way to code an always block within this common module so that it works fine in both kinds of designs? I am thinking we can use the async reset block like this -

```
always @(posedge clk or negedge reset_) begin
  if(!reset_) temp <= 'd0;
  else <do something>
end
```

If i use sync reset then in async reset designs i have a problem if clocks start much later than reset assertion-deassertion so the required reset can be completely missed.

In sync reset we know the posedge of clk and negedge of reset_ will coincide always, so is there any issue with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
always @(posedge clk or negedge async_reset) begin
  if(!async_reset) 
    temp <= 'd0;
  else 
    if (!sync_reset)
      temp <= 'd0;
    else
      <do something> 
end
```

and then tie one or the other reset to INACTIVE (`1'b1` in this case). If you're synthesising to an FPGA, I would imagine it would cost you nothing in area or speed. If you're synthesising to an IC, then I'd check what the synthesiser does with it.

Comment: A synthesis tool _should_ create a mux like structure for the D input of this flop and the sync_reset is the select, which is basically a sync_reset structure. It could however still create a negedge based flop, or it could create a flop with no set/reset. this would likely depend on the level of synthesis. I personally prefer generates for things like this with a parameter on the instantiation which sets it as async/sync. (although I'm basically in the async reset camp, and I use a reset synchronizer at the beginning of the reset structure :))

Comment: Well, i am still unclear on what is the possible issue if i still use async reset block on sync reset and not add the extra code as you have shown?

Comment: As I said, in an FPGA I suspect no issue flip-flop exists already; it will already have an asynchronous reset; not using it will just tie it inactive. In an IC (you don't say which you are synthesising to), as @I Steveo I says, you could end up with flip-flops with asynchronous resets being synthesised, which will waste area. (Flip-flops with asynchronous resets are slightly bigger than those without - ~15% bigger?.)